# I need to divided two columns of a CSV file in powershell and add the output to an object

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, division

I need to divided two columns of a CSV file in powershell and add the output to an object

```
 $ImportCSV = Import-Csv "#CSV file to read" 

$CSVArray = @($ImportCSV)

$CSVArray | ForEachObject {
    $battingAVG.result = [math]::Round($_.Hits / $_.AtBats)
    $battingAVG
}

$battingObject = New-Object System.Object
$battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $CVSArray.Name
$battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Note "BattingAverage" -Value $battingAVG
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output? Also what is wrong with what you have assuming we cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code-review with modifications. I've annotated in comments:

```
# Import-CSV already returns an array of objects.
# No need to wrap in another array
#ImportCSV = $CSVArray = Import-Csv "#CSV file to read" 
# $CSVArray = @($ImportCSV)
$CSVArray = Import-Csv "#CSV file to read" 

# Mispelling of 'ForEach-Object' below?
$CSVArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $battingAvg is undeclared at this point, so how does it have a 'result' property?
    # Maybe there's more to this variable that you haven't shared
    # $battingAVG.result = [math]::Round($_.Hits / $_.AtBats)
    $battingAVG = [math]::Round($_.Hits / $_.AtBats)

    $battingObject = New-Object System.Object
    # Now that you're inside the loop, get the Name property of the current record $_
    $battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $_.Name
    $battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Note "BattingAverage" -Value $battingAVG
}

# You want to create a new object for each row of the data, so this code
# belongs inside your loop
# $battingObject = New-Object System.Object
# $battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $CVSArray.Name
# $battingObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Note "BattingAverage" -Value $battingAVG
```

You should also do a bit of research on [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730948(v=technet.10)) and do some experiments; I'm fairly certain all of this code can be replaced with this:

```
Import-Csv "#CSV file to read" | Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name='BattingAverage';Expression={[math]::Round($_.Hits / $_.AtBats)}}
```